# MERN data submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a problem with connecting the front and back end on an application. I have routes that can successfully connect, but for some reason one does not transmit the information.

- my component takes form data information from the front end and executes the action with getFilteredQuotes():

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    filter: '',
    search: ''
  })

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

  const { filter, search } = formData

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(formData.search === ''){
      return console.log('Error, must put input in')
    }

    getFilteredQuotes(filter, search)
  }
```

- The the action then makes the call to the backend route:

```
export const getFilteredQuotes = (filter, search) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ filter, search })

  try {
    console.log(body)
    const res = await axios.get('/api/quotes/search', body, config)

    console.log(res)

    dispatch({
      type: GET_QUOTES,
      payload: res.data
    })  
  }
```

- at this point the console.log(body) shows that the data is as intended and in the same fashion as all of the other routes that I have that work fine. However, on the backend I have this:

```
router.get('/search', auth, async (req, res) => {

  const { filter, search } = req.body

  console.log(req.body)

  try {
    console.log(req.body.filter, 'pre-search')

    const results = await Quote.find({ [filter]: [search] })
    console.log(results)

    res.send(results)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
})
```

- And here is the problem, the console.log(req.body) now shows the data as {} and therefor the results are just an empty array []. The route with the same data works fine in Postman. The other routes and actions are arranged in the same way, but for some reason with this one the data isn't transmitted from the action to the backend request (but the call still goes through...). Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: you route `router.get('/search'...` is a GET request handler, you should use `req.params` instead of `req.body`

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I didn't know that about get vs post requests. Thank you very much.